# Dynamic http re-login function and module import python/django

Tags: python, django, urllib, cookielib

PART 1

I am writing a client to login remotely using urllib2, cookielib and urllib. Here is the code:

```
import urllib2 
import urllib
import cookielib
from mysite.settings import LOGIN_URL # see Part 2

login_data = {'username':'user', 'password': 'pass'}

login_data_encoded = urllib.urlencode(login_data)
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
response = opener.open(LOGIN_URL, login_data_encoded)
```

This code works and I can login. But I want to make a re-login function. Something like:

```
def login(username=None, password=None):
    login_data = {}
    login_data['username'] = raw_input('Please provide your username: ')
    login_data['password'] = raw_input('Please provide your password: ')
    return login_data
```

But if I do:

```
login_data_encoded = urllib.urlencode(login())
```

I can login once but when I want to login as a different user, I have to exit the interpreter. Isn't there a way to just re-login in the same script?

PART 2

I am running Django with the standard setup.

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        client/  # Folder I created, not an app
```

In client I have **_*init*_**.py and client.py but when in client.py I do:

```
from mysite import settings
```

I get mysite module does not exist. Do I have to create an app or does the standard python import not work in django?

Thank you

Comment: These should be two questions.

Answer (score 0):

From the client end, once the script is run and the server provides you the authenticated object (resource), then you can interact with it as long as the session exists unless you call an `Logout` url and then login again using other credentials.

Python imports work on all python applications. It looks like in your directory structure, you can trying to import a parent directory, Keep it at the level of manage.py and your import should work. Or for your case, restructure so that import is calling from the same level or use relative imports.

Comment: I understand the logout part but I cannot figure out the code for re-login with restarting the script. I have tried `from .. import settings` but it gives me `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`.